# String methods stopped working suddently

Tags: java, string, intellij-idea, minecraft

I was working with IntelliJ Idea for a while, and it worked perfectly, but suddenly, it stopped recognizing all the String methods. For example:

The `String.valueOf(boolean)` is actually showing me `Cannot resolve method 'String.valueOf(boolean)'`, `String.equalsIgnoreCase(String)` is also not working.

I don't know what happened, it was working every fine and suddently not. I am using IntelliJ IDEA 2017.3.1 (Community Edition), and I was working in a plugin for Minecraft Spigot, using craftbukkit-1.12.2-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-b1468.jar.

I've already tried to restart the program, rebuild the project and getting back on my steps until the point it was working.

I append you a photo of a piece of the code that is not working properly:
[image]

For example:

```
String color = args[4];
    if (color.equalsIgnoreCase("AQUA") ||
            color.equalsIgnoreCase("BLACK") ||
            color.equalsIgnoreCase("BLUE") ||
            color.equalsIgnoreCase("DARK_AQUA") ||
            color.equalsIgnoreCase("DARK_BLUE") ||
            color.equalsIgnoreCase("DARK_GRAY") ||
            color.equalsIgnoreCase("DARK_GREEN") ||
            color.equalsIgnoreCase("DARK_PURPLE") ||
            color.equalsIgnoreCase("DARK_RED") ||
            color.equalsIgnoreCase("GOLD") ||
            color.equalsIgnoreCase("GRAY") ||
            color.equalsIgnoreCase("GREEN") ||
            color.equalsIgnoreCase("LIGHT_PURPLE") ||
            color.equalsIgnoreCase("RED") ||
            color.equalsIgnoreCase("WHITE") ||
            color.equalsIgnoreCase("YELLOW")) {
        scoreboard.setColor(args[3], color);
        sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + 
                "Color of team " +
                ChatColor.GOLD +
                args[3] +
                ChatColor.GREEN +
                " has been set to " +
                ChatColor.GOLD +
                args[4]);
    }
```

This is my project structure:

[image]

My project window:

[image]

I just realized that this problem is only happening in my main method.

Hope you can help. PS: Sorry for my bad English, I am Spanish

Comment: Please include the source code of the class where you're attempting to use `String` methods.  I'm sure it wasn't "suddenly".  Something must have changed.  Did you name your class `String`?

Comment: You probably wrote a class called `String`, and now the compiler thinks you want to use your own class instead of the one that comes with the JDK.  Either remove or rename any file you might have created called `String.java`.

Comment: Click on the top level of the project in the project view toolbar window, and press key combination cmd+enter. This **should** open the Project Settings window. Make sure you're using the right JDK, and that IntelliJ can find it.

Comment: I've added some screenshots

Comment: Try restarting and invalidating caches (File --> Invalidate Caches / Restart --> Invalidate and Restart)

Comment: @asherbar Done it. Not working :(

Comment: Any chance you upgraded Java to 1.8.0_152?

Comment: I am using 1.8.0_151, should I upgrade to _152?

Comment: The simplest way to find what the problem is would be to hold down the Ctrl key and click the word `String` anywhere in your code.  Scroll to the top of the file that opens, to see the package declaration.  If it's not `package java.lang;` then your problem is that you've got your own `String` class.

Comment: Ok, that's the problem, I am using package com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.operations; Fixed it